# A set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is open, closed, and non-empty is $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is open, closed, and non-empty.  Prove $S = \mathbb{R}^n$.

*Proofs of this available.  My question is to verify my proof and respond to the follow up questions at the end.*

**Proof:** Let $s$ be an arbitrary point in $S$.  Let $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^+ : B_x(s) \subset S\}$ (with $B_x(s)$ indicating the open ball of distance $x$ around $s$).  We will show $D$ is not bounded.

Since $S$ is open, $D$ is non-empty.  Hence, if $D$ is bounded, $D$ has a supremum, which we call $r$.  We will show that the existence of $r$ leads to a contradiction, and so $D$ cannot be bounded.

(1) For any $d \in D, \overline{B_d(s)} \subset S$, since $S$ is closed.  But, since $S$ is open, this implies there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_{d+\varepsilon}(s) \subset S$ [see footnote*].  Therefore, $r \notin D$, because $r \in D$ would imply there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(r + \varepsilon) \in D$, a contradiction.

(2) For any $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon < r, (r - \varepsilon) \in D$, by definition of open ball and supremum.  The boundary of $B_r(s)$ therefore consists entirely of limit points of $S$ and is thus in $S$, since $S$ is closed.  As shown above, $\overline{B_r(s)} \subset S$ implies that there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_{r+\varepsilon}(s) \subset S$, again a contradiction.

Thus, $D$ is unbounded, and $S = \mathbb R ^n$.

**Questions:**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Is it well-organized and clear? The two cases I examined seemed similar enough that I'd expect I could merge them, but I was unable to do so.
3. It uses the axiom of completeness, implying that a metric space that admitted only rational or natural distances could have proper subsets that are open, closed, and non-empty.  Is that true? What's an example?
4. At the footnoted*, I implicitly assumed that if every point on the boundary of ball $X$ has a ball around it, their union includes ball $Y$, with $Y$ a proper superset of $X$.  This seems clear geometrically.  Am I allowed to assume it? Are there metric spaces where this is not true, and would they admit sets that are open, closed, non-empty, and proper subsets?

Comment: At 4., the fact is not clear geometrically. You know that there is a ball of some radius around each boundary point which is contained in $S$, but what if those radii shrunk to zero? There is no reason for every radius to be bigger than some $\epsilon$, right? It turns out that you can modify that argument, but as written it isn't correct. Which makes both (1) and (2) incorrect, unfortunately. The idea is to use a contradiction sequence : if there isn't an $\epsilon$ such that $r+\epsilon \in D$, then every $\epsilon$ fails, so there is a point in $B(x,r+\frac 1n)$ which is not in $S$...

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer The radii can be arbitrarily close to zero.  As long as they are above zero, then radius $Y >$ radius $X$.  Do you agree?  I don't argue that $B_{d+\varepsilon}$ is any specific size or approaches a limit, only that it is a proper superset of $B_d$.

Comment: I'm not comfortable, @SRobertJames. I'll put it this way : I can't come up with a counterexample right now, but I think there is one to your reasoning. You should not only have every radii above zero, but they all have to be at least $\epsilon$ for things to work out, right? The point is, you need to ensure that $B_{d+\epsilon} \subset S$ and I don't see how that happens if you just have a ball of some positive radius around each point , arising from openness. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: Using metrics at all is a bad idea here imo, since it disguises what's really going on... This holds for an arbitrary topological space that is connected

Comment: Agreeing with @SarveshRavichandranIyer. While #4 is in fact true (so he won't be able to find a counterexample), you haven't proved it. For an example where your might make a similar claim, but won't be able to prove it, take the set $\{ |y|\lt e^x\}$. At each point along the $x$-axis you can find an epsilon _square_ that is in the set, but you can't find a positive epsilon such that the epsilon-wide bar around the $x$ axis is entirely within the set.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Indeed, I see the folly of my ways, but you're right : the proof isn't as trivial as stated, and needs more elaboration than is present.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer - Heh. I wouldn't describe your comment as "folly". But I fear that the argument presented needs some sort of compactness argument (which is the difference between his example and mine), and if it hasn't been covered yet the OP will be stuck in the classic bad situation of having a true claim with no invalid proof.

Comment: SRobertJames - Have you covered "compactness"? If you have, then the fact that the boundary of $B_r(s)$ is compact would give you the strictly positive epsilon you want. Alternatively, if you've covered connectedness, then, as @BrevanEllefsen points out, you can do this without getting into all the ugly details. You should give us a better idea of what level you're at and what tools you have. Also, is it enough (for you) to prove the assertion, or do you want to stick with this approach?

Comment: My preference would be to point me in the right direction, whether it's refining this approach or using a better one.  Compact and connected are acceptable tools, though it's not immediately obvious to me how I would use them.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, then it's a very short proof. Try to use your set $S$ to construct a disconnection.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Maybe this could work (it doesn't look like compactness) : if there isn't an $\epsilon$ such that $B_{r+\epsilon}(x) \subset S$, where $r = \sup D$, then one can find points $x_n \in B_{r+\frac 1n}(x) \setminus S$. Now, $x_n \in B_{r+1}(x)$, so it is a bounded sequence, hence has a convergent subsequence(WLOG it is convergent), to say $y$. However, $d(x_n,x) \to d(y,x)$, so by the squeeze theorem, $y \in B_r(x) \subset S$ is a limit point of $S^c$, a contradiction to $S^c$ being closed. This was alluded to by me in my first comment, but I let it slide then.

Comment: I think this question deserves an answer after such a decent discussion. Perhaps I'll write one but I'll need 2 hours, so can't do it now. Perhaps 14 hours from now, it might be up.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer - Well, I'd say that "has convergent subsequence" is more-or-less compactness, but that's just a quibble. :-) And me, I'm lazy, so go ahead and write up your idea if you're inclined to - it won't interfere with any write-up I'd be doing.

Comment: If you only have compactness, fix your argument using the Lebesgue number associated to the compact set. If you have connectedness, suppose some proper subset $S$ is clopen and note $\mathbb R^n = S \cup S^c$ implies the whole space is not connected, which is absurd as it's path connected.

Comment: You can make things easier by reducing your argument to the one-dimensional case: if $\emptyset\ne S\ne\mathbb{R}^{n}$ choose points $a\in S, b\in S^{c}$ and look at what happens when you move in a straight line from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's that answer I said I'd write up.

---

###### Comments on your answer

This is a solution-verification, so first up : let's look at your answer.

> "Let $s$ be an arbitrary point ... and so $D$ cannot be bounded"

May I say that this is the first place that I've seen this argument, and I think it's a really good idea to consider it. Of course, the proof is correct to this point, but it's also novel in that I've not seen it anywhere else.

Cases (1) and (2) are also fine, right until I see the key point underlining each of them, as mentioned in 4., the last part of the post.

> If every point on the boundary of a ball $B$ has a ball of some positive radius around it, then the union of all these balls contains a ball which strictly contains $B$ and is concentric with $B$.

I felt that this statement was false, as written. However, it is in fact, *correct*. The justification, however, is somewhat difficult (at least at your level), which is why I was surprised that the statement was made with such confidence.

Let me try and list why I naively felt this was wrong. It is true that there is a ball of some positive radius around each point : however, if these radii happened to shrink to zero, then we should be in trouble, right?

Here's an example : if $d=2$, and we consider the unit ball $\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$. This can be parametrized by $\{(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) : 0\leq  \theta < 2\pi\}$. I was thinking along these lines : well, what if we had , like, circles of radius $\theta$ around every point $\theta \neq 0$, and then we had like a circle of radius $\frac 1{100}$ or something at $0$?

Something along those lines : the radii are positive, but their infimum is equal to zero. I thought that was wrong.

Turns out I'm wrong , so I'll put my final thoughts on your attempt this way.

> (1) and (2) are correct, and therefore the entire proof is correct. However, the justification for the Footnote* is perhaps too implicit at the level of OP, and should either receive further elaboration or be replaced by a more elementary assertion.

It is quite surprising that your attempt should create as much debate , but I'd just like users to visualize what I was trying to get at. Perhaps they shouldn't try to visualize why I'm wrong, because I think that's a fairly abstract argument.

---

Here is a proof of the Footnote* :

> Lemma : Let $B(x,r) \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a ball. For every point $y$ on the boundary of $B(x,r)$ (rigorously, this is the set $\{y : \|y-x\| = r\}$), let $r_y>0$ be a positive number (the "radius corresponding to $y$"). Let $$S = B \cup \left[\bigcup_{y} B(y,r_y)\right]$$ Then, there is a $R>r$ such that $B(x,R) \subset S$.

Proof : I think the easiest is the one that I suggested all the way at the starting, and uses the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem : any bounded sequence of elements in $\mathbb R^d$ has a convergent subsequence. It also uses the continuity of Euclidean distance.

Suppose that there is no $R>r$ such that $B(x,R) \subset S$. Then, for every $\frac 1n$, $B(x,r+\frac 1n) \not \subset S$, hence there is an element $x_n \in B(x,r+\frac 1n)$ such that $x_n \in S^c$.

Now, by choice, every $x_n \in B(x,r+1)$. Therefore, the $x_n$ is a bounded sequence, hence has a convergent subsequence, say $x_{n_k} \to x^*$. We claim that $x^*$ is a point on the boundary of $B(x,r)$.

To see this, note that $x_{n_k} \to x^*$, and the continuity of Euclidean distance, implies that $\|x_{n_k} - x\| \to \|x^*-x\|$. However, note that $r< \|x_{n_k}- x\| \leq r+\frac 1{n_k}$. Therefore, as $k \to \infty$, by the squeeze theorem, $\|x_{n_k} - x\| \to r$. Hence, $\|x^*-x\| =r$.

However, we claim that $x^*$ contradicts the hypotheses. Indeed, notice that $B(x^*,r_{x^*})$ must contain at least one of the $x_{n_k}$ because $x_{n_k} \to x^*$. However, $x_{n_k} \notin S$, therefore it is impossible that $B(x^*,r_{x^*}) \subset S$, contradicting the positivity of $r_{x^*}$.

Therefore, there is an $R>r$ such that $B(x,R)\subset S$, completing the proof.

---

Sam suggested a proof using "straight line" intuition instead of circles. That also makes sense : indeed, spheres in $\mathbb R^d$ grow out in all directions. If you can instead show that every possible line is contained in $S$, then you're done as well. This turns out to be a more geometrically easy proof, for various reasons.

To do that , let $l$ be any line and let $a$ be a point on $l$. Think of the line $l$ as an isometric image of $\mathbb R$ : that is, if we have two points $x,y$ on $l$, let $d(x,y)$ be the distance between $x,y$ , as if they were in $\mathbb R$. Now we will treat points on $l$ like real numbers.

Now, let $r = \sup\{\epsilon > 0 : x \in l , d(x,a) < \epsilon \implies x \in S\}$. It is geometrically obvious that $r = \infty$. Indeed, suppose not and let $r$ be finite. As $S$ is closed, we can find a "boundary point" i.e. a point $x^* \in S \cap l$ such that $d(x^*,a) = r$. However, $x^* \in S$ and $S$ is open, hence there is a ball of radius $B(x^*,r_{x^*}) \subset S$. This ball will intersect the line $l$, and travelling along the line $l$ it is clear that this ball contains points that are

- in $S \cap l$, and
- further away from $a$ than $x^*$, by travelling from $x^*$ in the direction away from $a$.

It follows rather obviously that $r$ cannot be the supremum from here, a contradiction. Hence, $r = +\infty$. Repeating this for all lines $l$ containing an initial choice of point $a \in S$ (by assuming $S$ is non-empty) tells you that $S = \mathbb R^d$.

---

ADDENDUM :

Indeed, the property discussed in the hypothesis : the non-existence of a non-empty, closed and open set $S$ which is not equal to $\mathbb R^d$, is equivalent to a property called the *connectedness* of $\mathbb R^d$. A space is connected if it doesn't have a non-empty proper subset which is both open and closed.

Connectedness is a purely topological notion, that does not rely upon geometric notions such as distances, balls etc.

Even though the above definition of connectedness is useful, it is typically not as utilizable in the above form as it is in this form(although both are easily equivalent) :

> A topological space is connected if and only if there is no continuous map $f$ from it to $\mathbb R$ taking only the values $0$ and $1$, such that both $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ are non-empty open sets. (This is typically stated in a different way, but I avoid that for convenience)

Using the above , one can use calculus to show that :

> $\mathbb R$ is connected.

Proof : If $f$ is any such map, then let $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y)=1$ for some $x,y$. Clearly $x \neq y$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ is continuous on the interval between $x$ and $y$, therefore there must be a $z$ between these points such that $f(z) = \frac 12$. This is a contradiction.

> A product of two non-empty connected topological spaces is connected.

Let $A,B$ be non-empty connected topological spaces, and let $f : A \times B \to \mathbb R$ be a map satisfying the conditions. Then, let $a \in A$, and let $f_a(b) = f(a,b)$. Then $f_a : B \to \{0,1\}$ is also seen to satisfy the conditions relative to $B$. It follows that $f_a$ is either constantly $0$ or constantly $1$ for every $a$. Similarly, defining $f_b(a) = f(a,b)$ for every $b \in B$, each $f_b$ is constant.

However, if $a \neq a'$, then $f_a(b) = f_b(a) = f_b(a') = f_{a'}(b)$ , so $f_a = f_{a'}$. Thus, $f$ is in fact a constant map.

In this way, we can show that $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^2$ is connected. Proceeding upwards by induction, every $\mathbb R^d$ is connected.

Note that this approach is extremely general, and also solves the problem.

---

NOTE : I haven't been able to make the compactness argument rigorous yet. I am not planning to do it because it seems infeasible in higher dimensions to be explicit about estimates and I don't want to handwave such an argument either.

Comment: Huh, interesting post. Never seen that union of balls things done that way. Of course, boundedness and closure are both used in the proof you gave, so one can do the same argument as the OP by simply pulling back to a finite subcover, considering the Lebesgue number of the covering, then choosing a larger concentric ball based on it contained in the finite cover (which might not be contained in all elements of the original infinite cover, but suffices for the OP's argument still)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I see, I'll study that argument carefully and edit it in when I can. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: You could probably cut out the Lebesgue number part by appealing to the fact adjacent balls on the boundary must intersect outside the circle (if they intersected on the circle, their point of intersection wouldn't be in the finite subcover since the balls are open). There are finitely many such intersections, so we can consider the minimum distance of the intersections from the boundary of the original ball and call it $\epsilon$. Now just add $\epsilon$ (or anything smaller) to the radius of the original ball.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That's right, I tried to make that rigorous but failed. It might be fatigue, though, so I'll have another go. If I can get both approaches right, I'll mentioned them.

Answer (score 1):

Great discussion! Very appreciative of such a vigorous response.

Responding to points 3 and 4 in the OP:

> 3. ...implying that a metric space that admitted only rational or natural distances could have proper subsets that are open, closed, and non-empty. Is that true? What's an example?

> 4. ...Are there metric spaces where [it] is not true [that if every point on the boundary of ball X has a ball around it, their union includes ball Y, with Y a proper superset of X], and would they admit sets that are open, closed, non-empty, and proper subsets?

Wikipedia lists two examples of [non-trivial clopen sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set), one which corresponds to point 3 and one corresponding to point 4:

3. The set of all positive numbers whose square is greater than 2 is clopen in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$ for exactly the reason anticipated in point 3.
4. In the metric space within $\mathbb{R}$ of $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$, the set $(0,1)$ is clopen.  I believe that this is because this space does admit such a thing.  For example, consider $b = B_{\varepsilon}(3)$. The union of balls around each point on $b$'s boundary is *not* a proper superset of $b$.

This suggests that *A complete metric space with non-trivial clopen sets must not have the union-of-balls-around-balls-is-a-proper-superset property*.  Is that true? Does the proof (with @SarveshRavichandranIyer 's additions) prove it?

Comment: I saw the response, thanks. I'll be replying to that, and the concerns of Brevan in an edit.

Comment: Regarding #4, a small ball around the boundary of $3$ *will* be a proper subset. You end up getting the ball $(3-\epsilon,3)$ which is a proper subset of $(2,3)$. You perhaps made the mistake of thinking you'd get points greater than $3$, but you don't since those points aren't actually in the space being considered (though they are points in $\mathbb R$). Compare to, e.g., an open interval being open in $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb R^2$. Everything else you wrote is correct... Note nontrivial clopen subsets are just connected components in any topological space, and $(0,1)$ is connected.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I agree that a small ball around the boundary of 3 will be a proper subset, and never said anything to the contrary.  Can you please clarify which statement of mine you are referring to?

Comment: So if $b$ is the ball described then the boundary of $b$ is the point $3-\epsilon$ and we can take a small ball around that point with radius $\delta$ and union it with $b$ to get a ball $b'$ centred ar the same point as $b$ of radius $\epsilon + \delta > \epsilon$. Just choose $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ small enough their sum is less than $1/2$. (Technically we can't center at $3$ like you wrote since it's not in the space, but we can center at any point to it's left, e.g. $2.9$, and the argument then holds.)

Comment: In any case, there is definitely a ball $b'$ which is the union of $b$ and a ball on the boundary of $b$ in the example you gave, contradicting what you wrote.

Comment: Your claim is obviously false without restrictions though, since we can just consider a one-point space $x$ with any metric (any will reduce to the zero metric) in which case there can't even be a proper superset of any ball around $x$. As a less trivial example of this form, define a metric on any space with multiple points (perhaps infinitely many) such that two points are infinitely far apart. Then a ball centered at one of infinite radius cannot have another ball as a superset. Obviously these are somewhat boring counterexamples to what you wrote,...

Comment: ... but they are important since they capture exactly the failure of a superset ball I think, since if your metric is finite and you have a ball of finite radius which doesn't contain all points then you can just consider a ball of larger and larger radius until all points are contained and you have the whole space... Just choose this ball at the boundary. You this need more clarification on "small" ball at the boundary. In general, I don't expect your argument to say much about connectedness at all outside $\mathbb R^n$ and spaces like it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Unless I am misunderstanding, a one-point space $x$ with zero metric, such that there can't be a proper superset of any ball around $x$, is _consistent_ with my claim: I claim that, in that space, a union of balls around ball $b$ is not necessarily a proper superset of $b$, and that is indeed true, as you have shown.  Please clarify your disagreement.